# Loading partial view using AngularJS in asp.net MVC application

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am creating an ASP.net MVC application.

I am loading a partial view in a div using jQuery and AngularJS as following:

I am doing an ajax call using AngularJS and storing the result as the content in div "courseList" using jQuery. This happens when the user clicks on links.

```
  angular.module('Domain', []).controller('DomainCtrl', function (
    $http, $scope, $window) {
    $scope.GetCourseList = function (domain) {
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/Showcase/CourseList',
        params: {
          domain: domain
        }
      }).then(function (obj) {
        $('#courseList').html(obj.data);    //jQuery code to load the content
      });
    };
  });
```

Html:

```
<nav ng-app="Domain">
  <h2>Domains</h2>
  <ul ng-controller="DomainCtrl" ng-init="domain=''">
    @foreach (var item in (List<string>)ViewBag.domains)
    {
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="GetCourseList('@item.ToString()')">@item.ToString() </a></li>
    }
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="courseList">    </div>
```

The above code works fine. But I am using jQuery to populate the `<div ID="courseList">`.

**How can I achieve this with AngularJS and no jQuery?**

Comment: obj.data will have the contents of the partial view say `<div><table>...` this will be inserted into the div `courseList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace calls to jQuery $ dollar e.g.

`$('#courseList').html(obj.data);`

with Angular's equivalent which is [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

`angular.element('#courseList').html(obj.data);`

Under the hood though, Angular will use jQuery if it's available i.e. you are including a version of jQuery in a `<script>` tag somewhere. Otherwise Angular will use `jqLite`, which is internally available as part of Angular itself.

Comment: it's working, can you explain a bit about the solution? How it works?

Comment: Have a read of the documentation for `angular.element`, which I included the url in my updated answer. That page should explain everything for you.

Comment: this is off topic but how can I load a popup kind of view inside the current page using AngularJS where I can do a form submit inside the popup window?

Comment: @RandomUser You're much better off asking that as a new question. It's best not to mix two questions on one page.

Comment: I haven't worked on it and if I post a direct question like this people are down voting such questions~

Comment: It's hard to help you with that question without seeing any existing code you have. If you have a popup window, then you need a `<form>` element in that window to do a `submit`. Or you could use `ajax` to `POST` data back to the server. I can't see why people would downvote that question, it seems reasonable enough.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in Angular way. You should declare [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) in the controller scope.

HTML:

```
<div id="courseList">{{ courseData }}</div>
```

And in your `then` callback, replace jQuery code with this:

```
$scope.courseData = obj.data;
```

Also set the initial state of `courseData` before `$scope.GetCourseList` method.

```
$scope.courseData = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="courseList" ng-bind-html="courseListHtml"></div>
```

And in your controller:

```
$http(...).then(function (obj) {
    $scope.courseListHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(obj.data);
});
```